# Sending Images over Async Server Client Chat C#

Tags: c#, server, client

I'm new to C# development. I'm working on a Server Client Chat application and I wish to enable image exchanging feature between the server and the client. I've tried alot of online tutorials but none adjusts to my code. Following is my code:

```
namespace ServerClientChat
{   


   {
```

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private TcpClient client;
        public StreamReader STR;
        public StreamWriter STW;
        public string receive;

```
    public Image img_to_receive;
    public String text_to_send;
    public Image img_to_send;
    public String UserName = "Asad";



    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        IPAddress[] localIP = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()); //getting own IP
        foreach (IPAddress address in localIP)
        {
            if (address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                textBox3.Text = address.ToString();


            }
        }

     //   textBox1.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(textBox1_KeyDown);
    }



    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Connect to server
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.textBox7.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Username.");
        }

        else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.textBox5.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter an IP address.");
        }

        else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.textBox6.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Port number.");
        }

        else
        {
            textBox7.Enabled = false;
            textBox2.Enabled = false;
            textBox5.Enabled = false;
            textBox6.Enabled = false;
            client = new TcpClient();
            //set client side endpoint consisting of client's ip address and port
            IPEndPoint IP_End = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textBox5.Text), int.Parse(textBox6.Text));

            try
            {
                client.Connect(IP_End);

                if (client.Connected)
                {
                    textBox2.AppendText(">> Connected to Server" + "\n");
                    STW = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
                    STR = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
                    STW.AutoFlush = true;
                    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();  //start receiving data in background (async means non-blocked communication
                    backgroundWorker2.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;  //ability to cancel this thread

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }

        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Start server
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.textBox7.Text))
        { 
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Username.");
        }
       else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.textBox4.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a Port number.");
        }

        else
        {
            textBox7.Enabled = false;
            textBox3.Enabled = false;
            textBox4.Enabled = false;
            textBox2.Enabled = false;
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, int.Parse(textBox4.Text)); //Listens for connections from TCP network clients.
            listener.Start();
            client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            STR = new StreamReader(client.GetStream()); //Implements a TextReader that reads characters from a byte stream in a particular encoding.
            STW = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
            STW.AutoFlush = true; //Setting AutoFlush to true means that data will be flushed from the buffer to the stream after each write operation, but the encoder state will not be flushed.

            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();  //start receiving data in background (async means non-blocked communication
            backgroundWorker2.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;  //ability to cancel this thread
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) //to receive data
    {
        while(client.Connected)
        {
            try

            {

                receive = STR.ReadLine();

                this.textBox2.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate () { textBox2.AppendText( receive + "\n\n"); }));
                receive = ""; 
            }
            catch(Exception x)       

            {
                MessageBox.Show(x.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) //to send data
    {
        if(client.Connected)                            
        {
            STW.WriteLine(text_to_send);




            this.textBox2.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate () { textBox2.AppendText(text_to_send + "\n\n"); }));


        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Send Failed");
        }
        backgroundWorker2.CancelAsync();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Send button
    {

           if(textBox1.Text!="")
        {
            text_to_send = textBox7.Text+":"+textBox1.Text;
            backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        textBox1.Text = "";
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult f = MessageBox.Show("Welcome to My Chat App! Do you want to start your own Server? ", "Welcome!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
        if (f == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            button3.Enabled = false;
            textBox5.Enabled = false;
            textBox6.Enabled = false;

        }

        if (f == DialogResult.No)
        {
            button2.Enabled = false;
            textBox3.Enabled = false;
            textBox4.Enabled = false;
        }

        if(f==DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

    }

    private void label5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            button1_Click(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    private void browsebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void sendimg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {


        }

        catch(Exception c)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(c.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: When sending data the receiver needs to know when the data ends. A stream stays open so the receiver doesn't know where the end of the actual data is located.  So when transferring data one or more of the following techniques has to be used 1) Ascii : Terminate with a known character 2) Ascii or Binary : Add a byte count to beginning of message.  Receiver reads byte count and then continues to read bytes until the count is reached.  3) Ascii or Binary : Every message has a predetermined length.

Comment: TCP breaks messages into datagrams which have maximum length of ~1500 bytes.  And TCP you can receive a datagram with zero bytes in the middle of the message.  The TCP receiver must loop and combine datagrams until end of message is received by one of the technique in my previous comment.

Comment: can  you please give an example?

Comment: A chat application doesn't have an application layer.  Your brain is an application layer that puts together the datagrams (sentences into words) and skips any spaces that exists.  When sending binary you have to send the exact number of bytes.  The simplest way of sending a binary image is to start the image with SOH (Start of Header 0x01) followed by  a byte count 0x12345678 then the image.  To convert a int size to a byte count use byte[] count = BitConverter.GetBytes(987654);